# Web page seems not to be loaded on old Android browsers, how to debug this issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, android-browser

I build a demo website ([sources](https://github.com/ceremcem/aktos-dcs-webui-example)) which uses socket.io connections and Ractive.js, and works just fine.

On desktop, there is nothing seems suspicious, but on the mobile browser, it seems to be loading forever. While it is loading, I can fully use the page. Only effect is, since page is using Javascript codes a lot, page responses is slowing down. When I click the "stop" button on the browser, it immediately stops loading "the rest" of web page and I can use entire page as intended, even faster (than it was loading).

I tried to debug with firebug, but I found nothing, because it works flawlessly on desktop browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would download the ADB plugin for Chrome, then i would look at performance profiling.  https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/cpu-profiling

Comment: there is no performance issue with the page, it is loaded in 900 milliseconds. this issue is only happening low-end HTC's browsers.